# Select input changes do not effect on model state

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select

А declare 3 select inputs with hierarchical data to be selected:

```
<select data-ng-model="current.manufacturer" data-ng-options="c.name for c in manufactures"></select>
<select data-ng-model="current.mark" data-ng-options="c.name for c in current.manufacturer.marks" data-ng-disabled="!current.manufacturer"></select>
<select data-ng-model="current.material" data-ng-options="c for c in current.mark.materials" data-ng-disabled="!current.mark"></select>
```

and data model like:

```
[{ name: "manufacturer_name", 
        marks: [{ name: "mark_name", 
               materials: ["material", ..] }, ...]}, ...]
```

When I select first input value, it makes second enabled; after second selection third option can be selected. But if I change first option, second input resets its value, but it doesn't effect on model value and the third element doesn't become disabled. The problem can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WRz9f/).

How to make value of `current.mark` to be changed when second input's selection changes?

Comment: You're never clearing `current.material` or `current.mark`.  It doesn't actually clear the value when you change the first option (you can still see the value at the bottom), but since you're selecting an object the select box clears.  For instance if you pick 'derp, 1, a' then switch to 'herp', mark stays '1' and material stays 'a'.  Since '1' doesn't exist in the new options for the middle select it is blank.  But since mark is still '1', the third select has the same options and 'a' is still a valid option.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat, http://jsfiddle.net/WRz9f/1/ after changing data to identical for marks and materials, second value desappeares too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mark` and `material` isn't being reset when you change `manufacturer`. I went ahead and added some watches to the scope so you can set the model values implicitly when something changes.

```
$scope.$watch('current.manufacturer', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        $scope.current.mark = null;
        $scope.current.material = null;
    }
});

$scope.$watch('current.mark', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        $scope.current.material = null;
    }
});
```

Seems to get what you want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tphalp/6YkJZ/)

Maybe someone else can solve it in a simpler way.

Comment: May be it is not the simplest, but 100% working answer, thanks!